# Exists similar functionality as Query Store in SQL Server

Tags: sybase

I would like to ask, if exists the same functionality Query Store in Sybase as in SQL Server?

Or can I join DB from Sybase to SQL Server as linked server and check showplans?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version are you using?

Comment: Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 PL09/EBF 29246 SMP/P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.31/ase160sp03pl09x/3839/64-bit/FBO/Thu Jul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAP (Sybase) ASE there are the MDA/Monitoring tables.  Among these are:

- [monSysSQLText](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/ad4a1ddf1bf34768841bd09d1eddf434/aba77962bc2b1014a7099503d8d5767d.html) - recently executed SQL text
- [monSysPlanText](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/ad4a1ddf1bf34768841bd09d1eddf434/aba74d20bc2b1014ae2f9a1a71b0998d.html) - query plans of recently executed queries
- both of these tables fall under the classification of [stateful historical monitoring table](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/9a57ec3c9937415eb6bf8c5abc91ca86/a8da677ebc2b1014813580c5ffd330e9.html)
- whether you find what you're looking for will depend on volume of query activity, amount of memory allocated by the DBA, and the type of query in question (eg, standalone SQL *vs* SQL inside stored procs & triggers *vs* SQL submitted as prepared statements); net result: don't expect to find 100% of everything you're looking for in these tables

Most (if not all) MDA tables are maintained in memory (ie, the table references - eg, *master..sysSQLText*, *master..sysPlanText* - are custom views of internal ASE memory structures).  This means the content of the tables go away when the ASE datasever is shutdown.  The volume of data stored in *stateful historical monitoring tables* is based on the amount of memory allocated (by the DBA) for these tables (aka memory structures).  Net result: the *stateful historical monitoring tables* are (effectively) implemented as a limited-memory circular list which in turns means that if you wish to capture the data from these tables for future use then you need a method of periodically querying these tables and storing the results (eg, in physical database tables).

See [P&T Series: Monitoring Tables](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/9a57ec3c9937415eb6bf8c5abc91ca86/a6615a93bc2b1014b21ac28b99447402.html) for more info re: MDA/Monitoring tables including associated ASE configuration parameters.